# maximum data size in a remote command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

my powershell script sends a file to several clients within customised session using following code (code is shortened)

```
function DoCopyFile
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $RemoteHost,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SrcPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $DstPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Session)
.
.
.               
    $Chunks | Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { `
        param($Dest, $Length)

        $DestBytes = new-object byte[] $Length
        $Pos = 0
        foreach ($Chunk in $input) {
            [GC]::Collect()
            [Array]::Copy($Chunk, 0, $DestBytes, $Pos, $Chunk.Length)
            $Pos += $Chunk.Length
        }

        [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($Dest, $DestBytes)
        [GC]::Collect()
    } -ArgumentList $DstPath, $SrcBytes.Length
.
.
.
}


$Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Node.Auth.Password -asplaintext -force
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ("{0}\{1}" -f $Name, $Node.Auth.Username),$Pwd
$Sopts = New-PSSessionOption -MaximumReceivedDataSizePerCommand 99000000
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Name -Credential $Cred -SessionOption $Sopts
DoCopyFile $Name ("{0}\{1}" -f $Node.Installer.ResourceDir, $Driver.Name) $Dest $Session
```

The full copy function is described here: http://poshcode.org/2216

The problem arises with a file larger than 52MB. it fails with following error:

```
Sending data to a remote command failed with the following error message: The total data received from the remote
client exceeded allowed maximum. Allowed maximum is 52428800. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (CLI-002:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
    + PSComputerName        : CLI-002
```

As you see in the code, i use customised ps session. when i set MaximumReceivedDataSizePerCommand to very low values (like 10kb) it fails with a message which tells maximum is 10kb, so i assume that MaximumReceivedDataSizePerCommand  is applied to ps session object.

Is it required to do this configuration on remote machine or somewhere else? what is causing this error?

thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You need to create a new `PSSessionConfiguration` (this to  not use the default one) in your remote computer:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name DataNoLimits #or the name you like.
```

Then configuring the parameter you want (in this case `MaximumReceivedDataSizePerCommandMB` and `MaximumReceivedObjectSizeMB`):

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name DataNoLimits `
-MaximumReceivedDataSizePerCommandMB 500 -MaximumReceivedObjectSizeMB 500
```

Then create the new session with the `PSSessionConfiguration` you need:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName MyRemoteComp -ConfigurationName DataNoLimits
```

in your local Computer.

In this way using the Send-File from posh.org I copy a file of ~80MB size.
Bigger size return me outofmemory exception.

More on this [here.](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7257.aspx#using-custom-session-configurations)

Comment: thanks for reply. Added new ps session configuration with proper values but didn't work either. i set it on localhost, executed enable-psremoting, restart-service winrm after setting the values. Also tried on 32bt/64bit powershell instances, no help.

Comment: @sardok Have you try changing $null to the max value of the size of your files?

Comment: yes i did but didnt work, actually what you suggested is nearly as same as my approach afaik.

Comment: besides that, if dont add this configuration to remote machine, script fails with following msg. Session configuration name is Installer here:

New-PSSession : [CLI-001] Connecting to remote server CLI-001 failed with the following error message :
The WS-Management service cannot process the request. Cannot find the Installer session configuration in the . .

Comment: @sardok You're right! Edited my answer... I've tested it and works! The `PSSessionConfiguration` needs to be created in remote comp.

Comment: Thank you very much! It did the job, now I can transfer alot more!

Answer (score 0):

I use copy-item over a session instead. I don't seem to experience a limit.

```
$session=new-pssession -computerName $server
copy-item -path "$tempfolder\$tempfilename.zip" -destination $destinationfolder -tosession $session
```

Answer (score -1):

You can look [this post](http://woshub.com/copying-large-files-using-bits-and-powershell/) about Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS). For more help, you can look also [MSDN documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj590836(v=wps.630).aspx). From the article, there are these considerations:

> The Advantages of Using BITS Protocol:
>
> - BITS is the intelligent protocol able to control the used bandwidth
>     not to affect the work of other network apps. BITS can use only the
>     free band and dynamically change the data rate during the transfer (if
>     other applications increase the network use)
> - A BITS task will be
>     automatically resumed in case of disruptions or computer restarts
> - A file can be downloaded in the background, unnoticed by a user
> - The recipient side and the server side do not require a deployed IIS
>     server
>
> Thus, BITS is a preferable protocol to transfer large files in
>   slow networks.

Hope that helps.